# Create a MongoDB database with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

The only way I found to do this is:

```
$mongo->selectDB('new_db')->createCollection('tmp_collection');
$mongo->selectDB('new_db')->dropCollection('tmp_collection');
```

Doing just `$mongo->selectDB('new_db')` actually doesn't work.
Got any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to run at least one command on the Database before it is created ...

This command can be run before you ***add*** any Collections ... so you can merely **list** (the nonexistent) Collections.

```
<?php

$connection = new Mongo();
$db = $connection->foo;

$list = $db->listCollections();
foreach ($list as $collection) {
    echo "$collection </br>";       
}

?>
```

Your new Database should now exist, with no user Collections created yet.

Comment: Mongo(); is deprecated now.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you don't need to manually create databases or collections in MongoDB due to its schemaless "lazy" way of creating databases and collections.

I understand if you're coming from an SQL world this doesn't make much sense. You may want to ask yourself though, "If it automatically creates a collection or database for me on the fly, is there really a need to define it ahead of time?"

Comment: Well actually I'm creating my admin UI so I need this feature.